# Equivalence between two topologies generated by seminorms - Follow up 2

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing, topological-vector-spaces

Another follow up question to clarify what I believe is the last bit I'm missing.

The original question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3480603/equivalence-of-topologies-generated-by-two-seminorms-and-section-6-2-rudins-fun?noredirect=1#comment7157384_3480603), while the first follow up is [in this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481730/equivalence-between-two-topologies-generated-by-seminorms-follow-up).

> Suppose we have two families of seminorms $p_\alpha$ and $q_\beta$. If for every $\alpha$ there is $\beta$ and a constant $C_{\alpha,\beta}$ such that $p_\alpha≤ C_{\alpha,\beta}q_\beta$ (and symmetrically for every $\beta$ there is $\alpha$) then they define the same topology. If the families are directed it suffices to consider only sufficiently "large" $\alpha,\beta$ because other seminorms are dominated by them. This is why the ordering helps.

The reference pointed was Simon's and Reed's book, where there's the definition:

> **Definition** A family $\left\{ p_\alpha \right\}_{\alpha \in A}$ of seminorms on a vector space $V$ is called **directed** iff for all $\alpha,\beta \in A$ there's a $\gamma \in A$ and a $C$ so tht
>   $$
> p_\alpha(x) + p_\beta(x) \leq Cp_\gamma(x)
> $$
>   for all $x \in V$. Equivalently, by induction, for all $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n \in A$ there's a $\gamma$ and $D$ so that
>   $$
> p_{\alpha_1}(x) + \ldots + p_{\alpha_n}(x) \leq D p_\gamma(x)
> $$
>   for all $x \in V$.

I can't relate this definition though to the fact that we can just consider indices sufficiently large.

Can you clarify?
Thank you very much

Comment: Let $p_1+ p_2 ≤ C p_3$ and consider on the one hand the topology generated by $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ and on the other hand the topology generated by $p_3$ alone. Obviously the first topology is finer than the second. But the second is also finer than the first, for if $p_3(x_\alpha- x)\to0$ as $\alpha\to\infty$ then $p_1(x_\alpha - x) ≤ C p_3(x_\alpha- x)$ which converges to zero and also $p_2(x_\alpha - x)$ converges to zero for the same reason.

Comment: Thus if you have that a semi-norm dominates a bunch of other semi-norms in the above sense, you can actually throw out the smaller semi-norms for the big one generates the same topology as all the small ones and the big one together.